# INSERT statement sqlite3 objective-c

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Hopefully my question has a simple solution.  I am just starting to use sqlite3 and I have created a database called `local` and a table called `table` with 1 column called `name` with type text.

It connects to the database fine its just I am trying to input a string value into the tables column but I think there is an issue with my INSERT text.  I know its probably something simple if anyone could just let me know where I went wrong.  Thanks.

```
SString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO TABLE(NAME) VALUES ('%s')", [key UTF8String]];
const char *insert_stmt = [inserStmt UTF8String];

sqlite3_exec(database, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Having a table called "table" is going to cause you all kinds of issues...

Comment: probably not an answer to your question but check out [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) on github - will make your life a lot easier

Comment: @lc Yes I know its simply for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you ignore any errors and don't display the error message, so if something goes wrong, you will have no clue.

Your second problem is that `TABLE` is a keyword;
to use it as a name in SQL statements, you have to escape it with double quotes:

```sql
INSERT INTO "TABLE"(NAME) VALUES('...')
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked.  I did have an alert setup to let me know whether it failed or not I just didn't include it in my post.